How to achieve the larger `framed' text?
Maybe I could't describe the result properly, but what I want is the text as follow:

Is there some packages to typeset that conventiently?
If my description is not so proper, please help me edit it, thanks!
Thanks to the comment, some relative links, I have tried the following:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage{luatex85} % for LuaTeX
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{CharFillColor}{rgb}{1,.8,.8}
\begin{document}
  \sffamily
  \textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.2pt,
    FillColor=CharFillColor,
  }{\Huge Lorem ipsum.}\lipsum[1]\textpdfrender{
    TextRenderingMode=FillStroke,
    LineWidth=.2pt,
    FillColor=CharFillColor,
  }{\fontsize{50}{18}\selectfont lorem ipsum.}
\end{document}

And it raised that:LaTeX Font: Font shape OT1/cmss/m/n' in size <50> not available (Font) size <24.88> substituted.I want to **typeset it as the TITLE of the book**, so it needs to **be larger** than\Huge`, is there better solution?


Depending on the font there's a package that might help. I think it's called outline

Or any of the questions linked from there, see the list at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/25221?lq=1.

It was contour I was thinking of

@Explorer If you want to render font in random sizes, choose a scaleable font like e.g. \usepackage{lmodern} (but that's completely unrelated to adding an outline, so voting to leave closed)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thanks, I will attempt for yr advice. It works!
